# Optimizing sphere fold function (GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

There is a sphere fold function, which transforms space based on the distance from origin. There are two constant parameters: `fR2` and `mR2`. The function looks like this:

```
const float fR2 = 1.0;
const float mR2 = 0.25;

vec3 s_fold(in vec3 v) {

    float mag = dot(v, v);

    if (mag < mR2)
    {
       v = v * fR2 / mR2;
    }
    else if (mag < fR2)
    {
       v = v * fR2 / mag;
    }

    return v;

}
```

It works, but because of the if-else branch, it runs slowly. It is possible to get rid of the branching, if I use the `step` function:

```
float a = step(mR2 , mag);
float b = step(fR2 , mag);

float sc = dot( vec3(
    1.0-a,
    a*(1.0-b),
    b
), vec3(
    fR2 / mR2,
    fR2 / mag,
    1.0)
);

return sc*v;
```

It is now a bit faster, but I would like to optimize it further. I've found a [one-line solution](http://www.fractalforums.com/3d-fractal-generation/a-mandelbox-distance-estimate-formula/msg21412/#msg21412), but it gives me a different result:

```
return v*clamp(max(mR2/mag,mR2),0.0,fR2);
```

It is unclear to me, how is it possible to calculate it with a single `clamp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if-else branch is a function like `res= v * F` where `F` is one of three possible values: a constant (fR2/mR2), a (hyperbolic) variable (fR2/mag), and a constant again (1.0).

`clamp(x, minVal, maxVal)` does this same logic (const-var-const). So you can write:

```
res = v * clamp(fR2/mag, 1.0, fR2/mR2); //with fR2 >= mR2
```

Let's write it in other way:

```
res = v * fR2 * clamp(1.0/mag, 1.0/fR2, 1.0/mR2);
```

We can avoid two divisions because `1/mR2 <= 1/fR2` implies `fR2 >= mR2`

```
res = v * fR2 / clamp(mag, mR2, fR2);
```

The final code is

```
const float fR2 = 1.0;
const float mR2 = 0.25;

vec3 s_fold(in vec3 v) {
    return v * fR2 / clamp(dot(v, v), mR2, fR2);
}
```

Both your solution and the posted "liner" suffer a potential division by zero when `mag=0`